# How to write $\sec^{-1}\left (\frac{x}{3}\right)$ in algebraic form?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I was asked to find$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x^3}\:dx$$

My answer was:

$$\dfrac{\sec^{-1}\left (\dfrac{x}{3}\right)}{6}-\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{2x^2}+C$$

The real answer is:

$$\frac{1}{6}\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{3}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{2x^2}+C$$

So they replaced the $\sec^{-1}\left (\dfrac{x}{3}\right)$ with $\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{3}\right)$.

How?

Comment: I wouldn't say that your answer is less real than the other.

Comment: My answer doesn't cover the entire integral

Comment: Try $\sec^{-1}(|\frac{x}{3}|)$ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below gives the main idea. Correctly defining the inverse secant can be a little tricky.

Suppose $\theta = \sec^{-1}(x/3)$.  Then $\sec \theta = x/3$ so that $\cos \theta = 3/x$.  Label a right triangle with one acute angle $\theta$, adjacent side $3$, and hypotenuse $x$. The opposite side has length $\sqrt{x^2 - 9}$ so that $$\tan \theta = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{3}.$$ Now evaluate $\arctan$ on both sides.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I wonder though why they decided to rewrite in terms of $\arctan$ ?

Comment: The inverse secant function is less common and there isn't universal agreement on its domain. There are no such issues surrounding the inverse tangent.

Comment: Yes that works out the best I think, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing now, but perhaps this is the path they followed when solving the problem:

First, integrate by parts to get
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x^3}\,dx=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{2x^2}+\int\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{x^2-9}}\,dx.
$$
In the new integral, let $u=\sqrt{x^2-9}$. Then $du=x/\sqrt{x^2-9}\,dx$ and so
$$
\int\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{x^2-9}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2+9}\,du=\frac{1}{6}\arctan(u/3)+C
=\frac{1}{6}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{3}\Bigr)+C.
$$

Comment: Perhaps they did do it like this. I used trig substition

Comment: In any case, my point was mostly that using another path of solving the problem yielded the arctan automatically. No particular choice was made of arctan over arcsec.